# Foreign key issue wont show a relation

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Here is the simplificated code of the db i m working on..i d like to have a relation between the table Episodi and comparein,in fact as you will see im using the foreign key but when i go on designer on phpmyadmin it wont show the relation...what s wrong ??

```
create table Serie(
  nome varchar(25) primary key,
descrizione varchar(400)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table Episodi(
  titolo_episodio varchar(25) not null,
  nome_serie varchar(25) not null,
numero int not null,
  durata time not null,
  data_trasmissione date not null,
  FOREIGN KEY (nome_serie)REFERENCES Serie(nome),
PRIMARY KEY(nome_serie,numero)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

 create table Personaggi(
  id_pers int auto_increment primary key,
  nome varchar(15) not null,
  cognome varchar(15),
  nazionalita varchar (15),
  nome_serie varchar(25),
  FOREIGN KEY (nome_serie)REFERENCES Serie(nome)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table comparein(
  id_pers int not null,
nome_serie varchar(25),
  numero int not null,
  primary key(id_pers,nome_serie,numero),
 FOREIGN KEY (id_pers)REFERENCES Personaggi(id_pers),
 FOREIGN KEY (nome_serie, numero) REFERENCES Episodi(nome_serie, numero)
 )  ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Have you [enabled the feature](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/relation)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67178/2

It showed up for me as an index. I believe if you are using innodb database, you would need to explicitly set these with a constraint or it will only put an index on them.

```
create table comparein(
  id_pers int not null,
nome_serie varchar(25),
  numero int not null,
  primary key(id_pers,nome_serie,numero),
 CONSTRAINT fk_pers FOREIGN KEY (id_pers)REFERENCES Personaggi(id_pers),
 CONSTRAINT fk_nome FOREIGN KEY (nome_serie, numero) REFERENCES Episodi(nome_serie, numero)
 )  ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: But it is showing the relation for the other table...

Comment: if you take the foreign key relation out for the personaghi table, does the foreign key for the episodi table show?

Comment: i don t know what this mean...But if i try to create this database i don t see the line that link: nome_serie and numero from the table comparein to the same attribute on tha table Episodi

Comment: are these innodb tables or myisam?

Comment: InnoDB at the end of every table i write that

Comment: what version of mysql are you using?

Comment: mmm..dunno...i m using xampp downloaded last week...on win 7... but i keep this problem from anoher pc using ubuntu so dunno..

Comment: type this: SELECT @@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS - make sure that it says 1

Comment: create table comparein(
  id_pers int not null,
nome_serie varchar(25),
  numero int not null,
  primary key(id_pers,nome_serie,numero),
 CONSTRAINT fk_pers FOREIGN KEY (id_pers)REFERENCES Personaggi(id_pers),
 CONSTRAINT fk_nome FOREIGN KEY (nome_serie, numero) REFERENCES Episodi(nome_serie, numero)
 )  ENGINE=InnoDB;

Comment: yes it says 1...(adding latest charter for comment XD)

Comment: no relation yet even with the code that you posted...

Comment: In older versions of mysql, you may have to create the index on the them, and then declare the constraint property manually...

Comment: i don t think that this is a very old version....There should be some logic error i don t know....id like to show youy this maybe i m explaining myself badly...

Comment: downloading..if you prefear i have a mumble server...

Comment: idk what that is...copy my name so i can remove that message